# To show set is closed and bounded in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, functions

I am having problem with this question , kindly please help me with this ,

Let $$S = \{x : x^{6} -x^{5} \leq 100\}$$

And $$T =\{x^{2} - 2x : x \in ( 0, \infty)\}$$

Then I have to show that set $S \cap T$ is closed and bounded. $S$ appears to be closed and bounded as it less than or equal to $100$.

Answer (score 1):

1. Set $S \cap T$ is bounded. Let $x \in S \cap T$. Then $x \in S$, so $x \geq -1$ (it's because $(t-1)^=t^2-2t+1 \geq 0$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$) and $x \leq 101$ (because for $t>101$ we have $t^6-t^5=t^5(t-1)>100$). So $x \in [-1,101]$, thus $S \cap T \in [-1,101]$.
2. Set $S \cap T$ is closed. Note that $S$ is preimage of set $(-\infty,100]$ under continous function $f(t)=t^6-t^5$, so $S$ is closed. Set $T$ can be written as $[-1,\infty)$, because continuous function $f(t)=t^2-2t$ reaches minimum at point $t=1$ and $\lim_{t \to \infty}f(t)=\infty$. Sets $S$ and $T$ are closed, so $S \cap T$ is also closed.

Answer (score 0):

Hint on being closed:

$T$ can also be written as: $\{x^2-2x:x\in[0,\infty)\}$ since $0=2^2-2.2\in T$

So both sets $S$ and $T$ are preimages of closed sets under continuous functions.

Hint on being bounded.

If a set is bounded then so are its subsets.